# How to show dialog when lwjgl game crashes (java)

Tags: java, dialog, lwjgl

I am using LWJGL to make my new game.

Quick Question:

When my game crashes with something like this:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
> at engineTester.MainGameLoop.main(MainGameLoop.java:376)
> C:\Users\users\AppData\Local\NetBeans\Cache\8.1\executor-snippets\run.xml:53: Java returned: 1

How do I get it to print it in dialog so that when someone runs it and it crashes they will be able to see it as a dialog that is has crashed

*Hope it made sense*

Comment: Other games that use LWJGL use Swing when OGL isn't working.  Just display a Swing dialog with the info.  I think also you should use logging; exporting a log file for you to review will have a lot more info that what you can fit onto a small dialog.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `try` ...`catch` and catch the exception (in a baseclass / superclass), send the user an error code that he can report and log a more detailed error. Depending on your configuration:

```
 ...
    try {
        /* game is playing() */
    }
    catch (MyGameException gameException) {        
       logging.log(gameException.log());        
       sendErrorCodeToTheUser(gameException);        
    }
```

I had a similar discussion with a colleague that a user can report an error code 1-10 or 1-1000 while the programmers can have a detailed log where the nullpointer was.

Answer (score 3):

I recommend using an UncaughtHandler to catch any exceptions that aren't handled and would actually crash the game. You weren't specific as to which version of LWJGL you are using, but if you are using LWJGL 2 it has a Sys class that lets you display an alert.

Sys.alert(Title, Message)

Unfortunately LWJGL 3 removed this class and GLFW doesn't seem to support creating message boxes at this time.

Set UncaughtHandler (First line in Main method)

```
Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler(UncaughtHandler.instance);
```

My UncaughtHandler class:

```
public class UncaughtHandler implements Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler{
    public static UncaughtHandler instance = new UncaughtHandler();

    @Override
    public void uncaughtException(Thread t, Throwable e) {
        Sys.alert("Uncaught Exception!", e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using lwjgl3, then you should use the [TinyFileDialogs binding](https://github.com/LWJGL/lwjgl3/blob/master/modules/samples/src/test/java/org/lwjgl/demo/util/tinyfd/HelloTinyFD.java)

Avoid swing if you can